# error code in console after using destroy function from chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

```
let myChart = null;
function draw(){

const labels = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < stats.length; i++) {

            labels.push(legend[i]);

        }


        const data = {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                backgroundColor: ['rgb(204,0,0)', 'rgb(241,194,50)', 'rgb(41,134,204)', 'rgb(106,168,79)', 'rgb(255,62,153)'],
                data: stats,
            }]
        };

        const config = {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: data,
            options: {
                radius: 200,
                hoverOffset: 30,
                aspectRatio: 1,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                responsive: false,

            }
        };
        if (myChart !== null) {
            myChart.destroy();
        }


        myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('defaultCanvas0'), config);

}
```

When i run this code my chart just keeps flickering and drawing itself over and over again with a new `id` each time. I need to be able to destroy my original chart before drawing a new one

**This is what `console.log` displays:**
[image]

**Edit:**

```
function HealthStudy() {
    //name for the visualisation to appear in the menu bar
    this.name = "Health study";

    //each visualisation must have a unique ID with no special characters
    this.id = "Health-study";

    //property to represent whether stats has been loaded
    this.loaded = false;


    // Preload the stats. This function is called automatically by the
    // gallery when a visualisation is added.
    this.preload = function () {
        var self = this;
        this.stats = loadTable(
            './data/health/causes-of-death.csv', 'csv', 'header',
            // Callback function to set the value
            // this.loaded to true.
            function (table) {
                self.loaded = true;
            });

    };

    this.setup = function () {
        if (!this.loaded) {
            console.log('stats not yet loaded');
            return;
        }

        // Create a select DOM element.
        this.select = createSelect();
        this.select.position(800, 380);

        // Fill the options with all country names.
        var countries = this.stats.columns;
        // First entry is empty.
        for (let i = 1; i < countries.length; i++) {
            this.select.option(countries[i]);
        }
    };

    this.destroy = function () {
        this.select.remove();
    };

    // Create a new donut object.
    this.donut = new Donut(width / 2, height / 2, width * 0.4);

    this.draw = function () {
        if (!this.loaded) {
            console.log('stats not yet loaded');
            return;
        }

        // Get the value of the country we're interested in from the
        // select item.
        var country = this.select.value();

        // Get the column of raw stats for country.
        var col = this.stats.getColumn(country);

        // Convert all stats strings to numbers.
        col = stringsToNumbers(col);

        // Copy the row labels from the table (the first item of each row).
        var legend = this.stats.getColumn(0);

        // Colour to use for each category.
        var colours = ['#CC0000', '#55a5f2', '#4dff00', '#f4e410', '#6a329f'];

        // Make a title.
        var title = 'Top 5 causes of death in ' + country;

        // Draw the Donut!
        this.donut.draw(col, legend, colours, title);
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you actually call the `draw` function? And some sample data could also be nice.

Comment: Hi i edited it to include the code!

Comment: but this code doesn't seem to have anything to do with your first `draw` function. Yes, it also calls a function named draw, but it seems to be a method of an object in your class.  Your first and second code snippet don't seem to be related, unless i'm missing something.

Comment: ahh yes theres a menu script also but if i were to add it here i think it would be too long. I just think it has something to do with the ```.destroy()``` and the creating of new chart